# Express.js урлы

Tags: node.js, url, express

Обратил внимание на то что есть две ссылки на одну и ту же страницу

```
site.ru/url/
site.ru/url
```

В router обрабатываю так

```
router.get('/url/', require('./url').get);
```

Раньше вроде бы express.js строго соответствовал прописанному url, а сейчас можно и со слешем в конце и без него открывать одни и те же страницы, а это как никак дубли.

Есть ли какие то настройки express для строго соответствия URL? Или опять таки придется делать перебор урлов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда создаешь роутер:

```
var router = express.Router({strict: true });
```

Или включи его, когда создается приложение:

```
app.enable('strict routing');
```

По умолчанию express.Router считает урлы /foo и /foo/ одним и тем же. Параметр выше как раз говорит, что это разные url.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает!